# SQLAlchemy query and get nested object instead of repeated row in one-to-many relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Suppose I have 2 tables initially:

Club table

| id | club_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | FC Barcelona |
| 2 | FC Milan |

Squad table

| id | club_id | squad_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | U19 |
| 2 | 1 | U16 |
| 2 | 2 | U16 |

When I want to query teams and corresponding squads with SQLalchemy, I would do something like this:

```
db.execute(select(Club, Squad.squad_name).join(Squad, Club.id == Squad.club_id)).mappings().all()
```

This would effectively return me something like this:

| id | club_name | squad_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | FC Barcelona | U19 |
| 1 | FC Barcelona | U16 |
| 1 | FC Milan | U16 |

I guess this is standard SQL practice - But obviously I get a lot of repeated columns, especially if we repeat the exercise and join all the players that belong to each squad, which belongs to each team.

i.e.

| id | club_name | squad_name | player_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | FC Barcelona | U19 | player_1 |
| 1 | FC Barcelona | U19 | player_2 |
| 1 | FC Barcelona | U19 | player_3 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 1 | FC Barcelona | U16 | player_1 |
| 1 | FC Milan | U16 | player_1 |

This produce a lot of data, and effectively repeating id, club_name and squad_name a lot of times.

I guess this leads me to three questions:

- Is it possible to write my statement in a way, so that I get objects returned instead of rows with repeated columns? effectively it would be neat to have something like this returned:

  ```
   {
       id: 1,
       club_name: "FC Barcelona",
       teams: [
           { id: 1, squad_name: U19, players: [...] }
       ]
   }
  ```

You get the point - Basically similar to what the ORM would produce with ORM objects, except that I produce the query myself and hopefully will achieve greater performance opposed to going through the ORM abstraction layer.

- Would It be better to do separate queries e.g.:

  ```
   clubs = db.execute(select(Club)).mappings().all()

    for each club in clubs
        db.execute(select(Team).where(Team.club_id == club["id"])).mappings().all()
  ```
- Is what I'm doing, what I'm supposed to be doing? i.e. receive all the rows with repeated columns and then serialize the rows into their correct object representations in my backend code?

If not already disclosed implicitly in my post post, I am an SQL rookie - Basically I'm looking for the solution which gives me the best performance.

Comment: when people say "ORMs are slow" they typically refer to the serialization / deserialization that happens, the query construction overload is usually negligible. You mention "receive all the rows with repeated columns and then serialize the rows into their correct object representations in my backend code" which is you repeating what an ORM would otherwise effectively do for you